# SharePoint 2013 Organization Browser HTML View Not Working

Tags: organization-browser

I've installed the Organization Browser and within Mysites both the Silverlight view and HTML view work.  Outside of Mysites I can only get the Silverlight view to work, the HTML view displays nothing.  Has anyone gotten this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

HTML View function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.UI.Portal.SimpleProfileBrowser.prototype.$2S_0 = function ($p0, $p1, $p2) {
var i = $p0.indexOf("|");
$p0 = $p0.substr(i+1,$p0.length-i-1);

        var $v_0 = $get($p1);
        if ($v_0) {
            $v_0.innerHTML = '<DIV></DIV><DIV></DIV><DIV></DIV>';
            this.$h_0 = $v_0.firstChild;
            this.$16_0 = this.$h_0.nextSibling;
            this.$1e_0 = this.$16_0.nextSibling;
        }
        if ($p2) {
            this.$h_0.innerHTML = String.format(SpsClient.ScriptResources.silverlight_Install_Message, '<a href=\'javascript:Silverlight.getSilverlight(\"2.0\");\'>Silverlight</a>');
            Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(this.$h_0, 'ms-profileBrowserHeaderText');
            Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(this.$h_0.firstChild.nextSibling, 'ms-profileBrowserSilverlightLink');
        }
        this.$2V_0($p0);
}
</script>
```

Steps to add Organization Browser in a SharePoint 2013

1. Edit the page
2. Click on Insert web part at the top navigation bar
3. Go to “Social Collaboration” category and select “Organization
   Browser” and click on Add button
4. Edit the Organization Browser web part and Expand Default Values and
   check “Only show HTML View” option and click Ok button

Steps to fix HTML View of Organization Browser

1. Edit the page (if the page is not in edit mode).
2. Click on Insert web part at the top navigation bar
3. Go to “Media and Content” category and select “Content Editor” Web
   Part and click on Add button.
4. Edit the content.
5. In the Ribbon, click on Edit Source under the Markup tab.
6. Copy-paste the code above.
7. Hide the Chrome and the content of the web part so that it would not
   appear on the page.

Solution to render HTML view:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23593.sharepoint-2013-organization-browser-web-part-does-not-render-in-html-view-for-windows-claims-users.aspx

Solution to render HTML view:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23593.sharepoint-2013-organization-browser-web-part-does-not-render-in-html-view-for-windows-claims-users.aspx